# How do prerequisites for promotions work?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I have trouble understanding how promotion prerequisites work. Civilopedia lists Accuracy I and Barrage I as being prerequisites for Volley, Cover and Siege.

However, all my trebuchets only needed Barrage I to access Volley and Cover I (I chose Volley). Now that one of them is ready to receive another promotion, only Cover I is available, Siege is not.

So I simply don't understand how the whole thing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where two prerequisites are listed for a promotion, typically you only need one or the other.

In cases where a promotion unlocks multiple other promotions, you can always pick the ones you turned down at future level ups.

However, in Gods and Kings, Siege was made into a Melee and Air only promotion, with the Air variant having 3 ranks.  Oddly enough, Siege is not available to siege units, such as artillery in the G&K expansion.  To compensate, most siege units default bonus versus cities is 200%, up from 20% in the base game.

Therefore, you're not missing the promotion by taking Cover or Volley - it simply does not exist.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the promotions available to an artillery.

http://imgur.com/3qQAmJ6

Comment: @user922764, I went back and tested this in a couple of games with the expansion on and off, and noted the results.  My previous answer was incorrect with respect to the expansion, I apologize.